# Determine GPU rendering power on runtime

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, gpu, android-memory

I'm developing an app that renders the camera preview straight to a custom GlSurfaceView I have created.
It's pretty basic for someone who uses OpenGL on regular base.

The problem I'm experiencing is a low fps on some of the devices and I came with a solution - to choose which shader to apply on runtime. Now, I don't want to load a OpenGl program, measure the fps and than change the program to a lighter shader because it would create definite lags.

What I would like to do is somehow determine the GPU strength before I'm linking the GL program(Right after I'm creating the openGL context).

After some hours of investigation I pretty much understood that it won't gonna be very easy - mostly because the rendering time depends on hidden dev elements like - device gpu memory, openGL pipeline which might be implemented differently for different devices.

As I see it I have only 1 or 2 options, render a texture off-screen and measure its rendering time - if its takes longer that 16 millis(recommended fps time by Romain Guy from [this](http://www.curious-creature.org/docs/android-performance-case-study-1.html) post) I'll use the lighter shader.

Or - checking OS version and available RAM (though it really inaccurate).

I really hope for a more elegant and accurate solution.

Comment: I think using a "first run" setup/optimization step is perfectly acceptable in this situation. Use a persistent flag to track which shader to use - and if this flag is not set, run a setup step where you perform the rendering and choose the appropriate shader. If you handle it correctly most users will not have any problem with this.

Comment: You may have a look into this Google I/O talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLVbLVtjDDw. They check how many calls to glClear() they can do in each frame before it affects the frame rate.